# Strong colimits of categories.

Tags: ct.category-theory, limits-and-colimits, fibered-categories, grothendieck-construction

Let $\mathcal C$ be a category and let $\mathcal F:\mathcal C\to\mathcal C\textrm{at}$ be a strong bifunctor. Given another category $\mathcal D$, let $\triangle_{\mathcal D}$ denote the constant functor $\mathcal C\to\mathcal C\textrm{at}$. Now define lax/strong limits and colimits as follows:

- A **lax limit** of $\mathcal F$ is a
  category $\mathsf{lim}\mathcal F$
  together with a natural equivalence
  $$[\triangle_{(-)},\mathcal
     F] \cong \mathcal
     C\textrm{at}(-,\mathsf{lim}\mathcal
     F).$$ Here $[\triangle_{(-)},\mathcal F]$ denotes the category
  of lax natural transformations and modifications.
- A **lax colimit** of $\mathcal F$ is a
  category $\mathsf{colim}\mathcal F$
  together with a natural equivalence
  $$[\mathcal
     F,\triangle_{(-)}] \cong \mathcal
     C\textrm{at}(\mathsf{colim}\mathcal
     F,-).$$
- We define **strong limits** and **strong colimts** by replacing lax natural
  transormations with strong natural transfomations.

Now, if my calculations are correct, a lax colimit of such a functor $\mathcal F$
is given by the grothendieck construction $\mathcal C\int\mathcal F$ and a lax limit is given by the category of **strict** sections
$s:\mathcal C\to \mathcal C\int\mathcal F$, i.e. the category $\mathcal C\textrm{at}/\mathcal C(\operatorname{id}_\mathcal C,\pi)$, where $\pi:\mathcal C\int\mathcal F\to\mathcal C$ is the opfibration corresponding to $\mathcal F$.

If we consider only the category of opcartesian sections, that is sections that map every morphism in $\mathcal C$
to an opcartesian morphism, we get a strong limit.

Now for the question:

**Is there an explicit description of the strong colimit of a functor $\mathcal F:\mathcal C\to\mathcal C\textrm{at}$?**

Comment: There is no tricategory or bicategory of bicategories and functors whose 2-cells are lax transformations (try to define the whiskering ($F \circ \alpha$).

Comment: Tank you. This was a point i did not really consider.

Comment: This does not make the question obsolete, right?
(I fixed the question, btw.)

Comment: Have a look at Tim Porter's Crossed Menagerie http://ncatlab.org/timporter/show/crossed+menagerie section 8.2.10 and also http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0408298 chapter 3.

Comment: FWIW, I think what you have called a "lax colimit" should more properly be called an "oplax colimit", as confusing as it may be; see the discussion at http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/2-limit#lax .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adapted from the papers by Fiore and by Porter that I referred to above:

To form the usual lax colimit of P we take the disjoint union of the $P_i$ for each $i \in C$ and then adjoin new arrows to represent the action of P: for each $m \colon i \to j$ in C and each $X \in P_i$ there is an arrow $X \to Pm(X)$.  Then we quotient by a congruence that ensures that the assignment of $X \to Pm(X)$ to $X$ is lax natural.  This lax transformation is the universal cone.

To form the pseudo colimit we simply make sure each $X \to Pm(X)$ is an isomorphism: adjoin a formal inverse along with it and add the requisite equations to the congruence.

Comment: Yes, this is the right answer. In order to prove it one can either follow the construction given by Tom Fiore or split it into two parts: First, we establish the grothendieck construction as a lax colimit. Then, we realize that among all cones the strong cones correspond to functors that send every morphism $X\to Pm(X)$ and thus every (op)cartesian morphism to an isomorphism. These functors however correspond to functors out of the localisation of the grothendieck construction along all (op)cartesian morphisms.